# How to deploy compiled huff contract bytecode (compiled) using create2

Tags: ethereum, remix

I am trying to use a Create2Factory contract (https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000ffe8b47b3e2130213b802212439497#code) to deploy another smart contract written in huff on to a predetermined address using a precomputed salt.

I have the compiled bytecode for the huff contract and salt ready and I want to deploy the huff contract bytecode but neither Remix IDE nor MyEtherWallet are allowing me to call the safeCreate2 of the aforementioned Create2Factory to deploy my compiled huff contract.

How can I use the compiled ByteCode on RemixIDE, MyEtherWallet or another tool to deploy the same using Create2Factory contract?

[image: error when trying to enter bytecode in MyEtherWallet]

Answer (score 1):

When querying the Create2Factory for an address, in my experience, you're just validating that your computed address is actually correct.  You would instead use the init code hash of your contract, not the init code, as well as the computed salt for your desired address.  The salt should begin with 20 bytes that are equal to your 'owner'/'sender' account.

Once you verify that the init code hash + salt == the address you computed, then you call the write function to actually deploy, passing in then the salt + init code.

Let me know if this is not clear, or if you'd like to use my Create2Factory which I have had no issues with.

Also, on MEW are you prefixing with 0x?  Can't tell if that's the beginning of the line in the picture or not.

Check out the Create2Crunch git repo, that Create2Factory contract is much better.

https://github.com/0age/create2crunch

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled back across this post and realized what your problem is most likely.

When using Remix / MEW, ensure that any *non-address* hex values are wrapped in quotes (either single or double quotes will work).

Apologies for not realizing this when I first replied.